# Absolute positioned div sticking out of a scrollable fixed position div

Tags: css, css-position

I have a page with a fixed scrollable sidebar. When hovering one of the buttons in the sidebar I want to show a popup/tooltip beside the button. The tooltip however is larger than the sidebar, so it needs to stick out from it.

That is where the problem start. I can't get the tooltip to go outside the fixed container. It is cut when it reaches the edge of the sidebar.

This appears to have something to do with it being scrollable. If I remove overflow-y: scroll from the sidebar the tooltip starts to work, but when it is scrollable it does not. The same happens both if I just move the sidebar to the right using margins, and if I absolutely position it based on the element you hovered.

If I make the tooltip fixed it works, until I start to scroll the sidebar and the tooltip does not follow. The tooltip is fixed based on the starting position, not the current position.

Here is a fiddle showing the three cases:
http://jsfiddle.net/8VF22/2/

Basic html and css:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="button">Hover me
            <div class="tooltip">This tooltip hates my life and won't go outside the sidebar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

So how to go about this? Is there anyway to get something to show outside a scrollable fixed container and keep it aligned with the sidebar when you scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append your tooltip div to body, not to sidebar. Since you set overflow-y to scroll for sidebar, overflow-x automatically set up to hidden or auto, but not to visible.

Comment: But if I did that, how would I position the tooltip beside the item I am hovering?

Comment: You can set position of tooltip to absolute and then calculate position of button relatively to document (for example, using jQuery.offset http://api.jquery.com/offset/ ) and then setup offset of tooltip. Also you will need to specify z-index of tooltip.

Comment: Also if your page used jquery.ui you can use position util method http://jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: I was hoping to do this with css, if there is a way.

Comment: then you need to avoid using overflow-y: scroll in some way

Comment: Which I can't since I need to scroll the element. Sometimes css makes me sad :( But thanks anyway, good to have confirmation that I can't solve it with just css.